# Why do Constructors, unlike Methods, do not retain the name of their parameters in Java?

Tags: java, methods, reflection, constructor

In Java, when using reflection you can access the name of each parameters of a Method using the following code:

```
Parameter[] parameters = method.getParameters();
String parameterName = parameter[<index of desired parameter>].getName();
```

However, doing so is impossible using the standard reflection API for Constructors. Why so?

Comment: Why do you think it's impossible?  `getParameters` comes from the parent shared by both `Method` and `Constructor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, doing so is impossible using the standard reflection API for Constructors.

I don't think that is correct.  The approach above *should* work the same if you apply it to a `Constructor` or a `Method`.  The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Executable.htm) says that.

You might be seeing a case where the parameter names that you see don't correspond to the source code.  The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Executable.html#getParameters--) says that is possible too:

> *"The parameters of the underlying executable do not necessarily have unique names, or names that are legal identifiers in the Java programming language (JLS 3.8)."*

It is probably due to the way that the classes you are trying to introspect were compiled.  If you can recompile them from source code with full debug information (see the javac -g flag) the names should be there.

Comment: Would you point me to the correct function? Because I cannot find any such function in there https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html .
Edit: nevermind, I just found out that getParameters(); is inherited from the Executable class. Thank you!